# Rendering and image quality in MATLAB figures

Tags: matlab, rendering, figures

I have a contour plot and I am using the current rendering:

```
set(gcf, 'renderer', 'zbuffer');
```

but it is giving me this thick red line in the plot and I don't know how to get rid of it. I tried switching to:

```
set(gcf, 'renderer', 'opengl');
```

but the quality is poor and I really need to have high quality images. Any suggestions?

Comment: What are you trying to render? Sample code please ..

Comment: Maybe, this will help: http://www.mathworks.com/support/tech-notes/1200/1201.html

Answer (score 19):

In general, I let MATLAB choose which renderer is most appropriate, which means leaving the [`RendererMode` property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure-properties.html#property_d0e272585) of the figure set to its default value of `auto`. A brief description of the current `'Renderer'` options can be found [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/figure-properties.html#property_d0e272286).

I'll address your two problems separately:

- **A "thick red line" in the contour plot:** Without seeing the code you use to make the contour plot, or a screenshot, I can't help you much with this other than to point out that you can control aspects of how the [contour plot](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour.html) renders by setting certain [contour plot properties](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour-properties.html). For example, you can control the line width by setting the `LineWidth` property:

  ```
  [C, h] = contour(peaks(20), 10);  % Make a sample contour plot
  set(h, 'LineWidth', 3);           % Make the lines thicker
  ```
- **Figure "quality":** The choice of renderer doesn't so much adjust the *quality* per se. The renderer generally influences the accuracy and speed of the graphics rendering as well as the rendering options available (i.e. lighting, transparency, etc.). If you want better *quality* images from your figures, I would suggest downloading the submission [Myaa](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/20979) by [Anders Brun](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/authors/31267) on [The MathWorks File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/). It allows you to create anti-aliased graphics in MATLAB. Here's a screenshot from the submission illustrating the improved figure quality:

  [image]

Comment: I've been looking for this for several months (particularly in relation to Latex in 3D OpenGL figures, but nonetheless)! Thank you, thank you, thank you for the link!