# MATLAB and high quality EPS figures

Tags: matlab

I am looking to export my MATLAB plot as a high quality figure. Specifically, I would like to save it as a vector based file format such as EPS or SVG.

```
I have tried print and saveas commands:
saveas(h,'myFileName','epsc2');
print('-r150','-depsc2', 'myFilename');
```

On all occasions this produces poor quality parts of the graph, although the axis-labels are indeed vector. Why does MatLab do some horrible rendering before putting it into an EPS?

Example of poor quality plot here:
http://users.ox.ac.uk/~pemb2372/myFileName.eps

**Edit:**
It is also worth noting that if you use a Mac viewing an EPS file from Matlab, 'Preview' app may render inner graph content rasterized and poor quality, while leaving the axis and labels vectorized and high quality. This is very misleading but when you open said EPS file in, for example, Inkscape, the quality is actually vector and quite high.

**Edit 2:**
My university hosting account has expired, so you can no longer view the figure. Suffice it to say that it showed a poor quality raster-style plot within high quality beautiful axis lines, ticks and labels.

Comment: I can't explain "why" Matlab has such poor stock features, but you may want to try [export_fig](https://sites.google.com/site/oliverwoodford/software/export_fig). It's available on Matlab File Exchange and has helped me a lot. You will also need to install ghostscript if you don't have it already.

Comment: Ok thanks - I'll look into this and report back

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Matlab can export to pdf with better quality than EPS, but with its own caveats of setting decent margins and font sizes.

**edit**:
Examples are similar to the EPS case as explained in the help of e.g. [`print`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/techdoc/ref/print.html):

```
saveas(gcf,'filename.pdf')
```

or

```
print('-dpdf','filename.pdf')
```

You might also want to take a look at the `PaperSize`, `PaperPosition` and `PaperUnits` properties of your figure (by means of the `set` and `get` functions).

**edit**: Another option is to use one of the functions available on [FileExchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange) such as the ones mentioned by @user664303 below. My personal favorite for use with LaTeX is [`matlab2tikz`](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/22022-matlab2tikz) for which the latest version can be gotten from [GitHub](https://github.com/matlab2tikz/matlab2tikz). Together with the [`external`](http://www.howtotex.com/tips-tricks/faster-latex-part-ii-external-tikz-library/) library of TikZ, I think this delivers some of the most nicest graphs around.
Probably it's also best to mention that I have been actively involved in the `matlab2tikz` project since 2012.

Comment: Are you able to provide an example?

Comment: I added some small examples, nothing much as they are practically identical to the EPS case.

Comment: Although silly, I thought it might be worth sharing this nuget of knowledge. Part of the reason I was having problems with this whole issue was that the 'Preview' on the Mac OS X was not rendering the images properly. This made them look even worse and compounded my issues. Lesson, use a proper image editor to previous your files!

Answer (score 13):

I thought I would share the issue I had, and how I overcame it...

I was getting terrible results because I had the wrong renderer set to default. In my `startup.m`, I had the `zbuffer` renderer enabled. This is an example eps output.

[image: Crop of output eps]

I made that eps output with: `print(gcf,'-depsc2','filename.eps')`. This eps is so OBVIOUSLY rasterised. It makes me angry at matlab. Then, I had a brainwave - perhaps my default renderer `zbuffer` is interfering with the image save process. So, adding the line:

```
set(gcf,'renderer','painters')
```

and running the print command as before, here is the output:

[image: Crop of second output eps]

Note that I just took screenshots of the eps output files at 100%. And I can confirm the second image is actually vector. Here is a good question/explanation on choosing [Renderers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1281947/rendering-and-image-quality-in-matlab-figures?rq=1) in MATLAB.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. This basic issue really shouldn't be causing so much headache!= for everyone!

Comment: Note: it should be `'-depsc2'`, not `'depsc2'` for the second argument of the `print(..)` command.

Comment: @EvgeniSergeev - correct, my bad! I've edited in that correction.

Answer (score 11):

The [export_fig](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629) function on the MATLAB file exchange is a reasonably reliable way of accurately exporting figures to eps and pdf (as well as bitmap formats) in MATLAB.

The [plot2svg](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7401) function, also from the file exchange, allows you to export in svg format. It provides some additional benefits, such as being able to export translucent patch objects in vector format.

A comparison of exporting methods is given in this [blog post](http://www.matthiaspospiech.de/blog/2010/10/11/matlab-figures-solving-export-problems/).

Comment: `export_fig` is the boss.

Answer (score 0):

I always acquire the final plots (those which are supposed to be inserted into papers and publications) by `matplotlib` library of `python`.

You can bet on the amazing quality of the generated plots, both `.pdf` and `.eps` formats.