# Why my axis texts looks so bad in Matlab when I use eps format?

Tags: matlab, figure, eps

As you can see in my screen shot (the picture quality has changed since I changed the format to import it here but texts looks as bad as this in Word), when I import my eps figures to word my figures text looks bad. It only happens in Windows PCs (I tried it in Mac, it was OK) and it only affects the text not the figure lines or objects. 
I tried everything in this [tread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8280971/matlab-and-high-quality-eps-figures) but I still have the problem and my problem is kind of opposite of this tread since I get a good figure with bad labels!

[image]

Comment: No point saving an eps for use in Word, as Word doesn't handle vector graphics. Save it as a bmp at the same size you are going to use it, and it should be fine.

Comment: It's been a long time since I last used Word; however, I remember that, although *.eps and *.pdf inserted in a document looked bad, the printed result looked crisp. Have you tried to print out the document?

Answer (score 1):

I had similar problems when I tried to import Matlab-made eps-figures into Ipe. The problem was that the standard font used by Matlab (depending on he version mostly Helvetica) is not an open one but has to be bought (if it does not come with the program you use). Therefore, it could not be used properly by Ipe but was instead vectorized in a poor way.

So what you could try is to change the plotting font of Matlab to some Microsoft compatible font (Verdana for example).

Sorry for using the answer function for this suggestion, but new users are apparently not allowed to comment...