# Export scatter3 figure to a vector graphics format

Tags: matlab, svg, export, matlab-figure, vector-graphics

I have the 3D figure in Matlab. The code to create such type of figures:

```
%% Generate dummy data
N = 100;
x = randn(N,1);
y = randn(N,1);
z1 = randn(N,1);
z2 = z1 -10;
%% Make a plot
F = figure()
hold all
scatter3(x,y,z1)
scatter3(x,y,z2)
view([80,30])
axis square
%% try to export figure
print(F,'export_test','-depsc');
```

The exported file,  when I open it in Illustrator looks really strange - it is subdivided to 4 bitmap parts.

**Could You help me to export this plot to some vector format?**

Comment: Please show us the desired output (i.e. the figure window) and the output you're seeing - to form a [mcve].

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8280971/8239061